# editing vold.fstab

Tags: swap

I believe that I can swap memory SDcard <---> extSdCard if I know how to edit the vold.fstab. Can someone here please help me? I know it'll be a piece of cake for the geniuses here at stackexchange.

My phone is Samsung GT-I8552 ( Quattro / Win )

Here is my vold.fstab

```
## Vold 2.0 Generic fstab
## - San Mehat (san@android.com)
##

#######################
## Regular device mount
##
## Format: dev_mount <label> <mount_point> <part> <sysfs_path1...>
## label - Label for the volume
## mount_point - Where the volume will be mounted
## part - Partition # (1 based), or 'auto' for first usable partition.
## <sysfs_path> - List of sysfs paths to source devices
######################
#storage_struct = series, "/mnt/sdcard/extStorages"
#storage_struct = parallel

{
supported_exfat = yes
android_secure_containers = enable
}
dev_mount sdcard /storage/extSdCard auto /devices/platform/msm_sdcc.1/mmc_host/mmc1/

#usb host device
{
media_type = usb
supported_exfat = yes
}
dev_mount sda /storage/UsbDriveA auto /devices/platform/msm_hsusb_host/usb

#usb host device
{
media_type = usb
supported_exfat = yes
}
dev_mount sdb /storage/UsbDriveB auto /devices/platform/msm_hsusb_host/usb

#usb host device
{
media_type = usb
supported_exfat = yes
}
dev_mount sdc /storage/UsbDriveC auto /devices/platform/msm_hsusb_host/usb

#usb host device
{
media_type = usb
supported_exfat = yes
}
dev_mount sdd /storage/UsbDriveD auto /devices/platform/msm_hsusb_host/usb

#usb host device
{
media_type = usb
supported_exfat = yes
}
dev_mount sde /storage/UsbDriveE auto /devices/platform/msm_hsusb_host/usb

#usb host device
{
media_type = usb
supported_exfat = yes
}
dev_mount sdf /storage/UsbDriveF auto /devices/platform/msm_hsusb_host/usb
#EOF
```